# Update the nth row on a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update the nth row (every 2nd row in this case) and it's not working.

SELECT 'BEFORE'

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[User]
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #t1_AlreadySelected (t1_UserId int) 

CREATE TABLE #t2_NotSelected (t2_UserId int) 

INSERT #t1_AlreadySelected (t1_UserId)  
    SELECT UserId
    FROM dbo.[User]
    WHERE ((SelectedForPublicViewSwitch = 1) AND (ActiveSwitch = 1))
```

SELECT 'Already selected'

```
SELECT *
FROM #t1_AlreadySelected
```

[image]

```
-- Get the not selected.
INSERT #t2_NotSelected (t2_UserId)  
    SELECT UserId
    FROM dbo.[User]
    WHERE (((SelectedForPublicViewSwitch = 0) AND 
            (ActiveSwitch = 1) AND (AdminSwitch = 0))
           AND UserId NOT IN (SELECT t1_UserId FROM #t1_AlreadySelected))
```

SELECT 'Not selected'

```
SELECT * 
FROM #t2_NotSelected
```

[image]

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- Update the nth row of the rows not previously selected.
    UPDATE dbo.[User]
    SET SelectedForPublicViewSwitch = 1 
    WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId 
                     FROM 
                         (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId ASC) AS rownumber, UserId
                          FROM #t2_NotSelected) AS tmp
                     WHERE rownumber % 2 = 0)
```

SELECT 'AFTER UPDATE'

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[User]
```

[image]

I would expect UserId 5 and 7 to NOT be set but they were.

Comment: why you don't use UserIds for nth row?

Comment: Mr. AF. That worked. Thanks. How do I give you credit?

Comment: Also, How do I limit it to updating only say 5 of the universe I nth threw? In this small test I tried add in TOP 1 in the select of the subquery but it had no affect.

Comment: i couldn't understand `How do I limit it to updating only say 5 of the universe I nth threw?`

Comment: If I have 120 rows in my user table, 110 not selected previously (that's now my universe), so I want to nth threw say every 2 and update but stop after the 5th nthed row set. As coded, it will nth threw them all and set each nthed row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UserId`(s) as nth row.because, `UserId`(s) starts from 1 and looks auto incremental.

in order to update rows that their position is in multiple of 5 use below query

```
UPDATE dbo.[User]
SET    SelectedForPublicViewSwitch = 1 
WHERE  UserId IN (
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM #t2_NotSelected 
    WHERE  UserId % 5 = 0 // Multiple of 5
    )
```

Above query returns rows that are multiple of 5 from `#t2_NotSelected` table like: `5 10 15 20 ..`. and updates values of `SelectedForPublicViewSwitch` to `1` in the table of `User`

Comment: It did not like the ORDER BY. I removed it. Then it ran and produced my expected results. Error Message was: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: I also partially changed it to: (SELECT t2_UserId FROM #t2_NotSelected WHERE  t2_UserId % 2 = 0) and I get the same results I expect. It worked the other way but I believe it should be coded as I now have it. Lastly I added: TOP 2 after the before the t2_UserId. This will stop updating after 2 of the nthd entries which is what I want.